# Identify terms in an expression (Maple)|

Tags: maple

How hard is to program that given a symbolic expression like

$$
f = x^2 + y^2 + k \, ,
$$
I could teach to Maple that $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ and then it expresses f like

$$
f = r^2 + k \, ?
$$

Of course I want to implement it for more difficult expressions but this would be a good start.

Comment: do you want to know how to write an  equation of a circle in Maple ????

Comment: Do you want your expressions *automatically* transformed, or would it be okay if you had to enter a command to do it? The automatic is difficult, but I think doable. I'd have to research how to do it. The command is easy. And, are your "more difficult expressions" still polynomial? The polynomial case is easier than the non-polynomial.

Comment: @mounirbensalem: No, not a circle. The OP is clearly and statedly just providing a simplified example of something more general that is desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expressions are polynomials then you can apply the `algsubs` command to get that form.

```
restart:

expr := f = x^2 + y^2 + k:

rule := x^2 + y^2 = r^2:

algsubs(rule, expr);

                                   2
                              f = r  + k
```

A more powerful way to obtain `f` expressed like that, which will work for a broader class of expressions, is to simplify it under side relations. Eg,

```
restart:

expr := f = x^2 + y^2 + k:

rule := x^2 + y^2 = r^2:

simplify( expr, {rule} ); 

                                   2
                              f = r  + k
```

A more automatic mechanism is to use the `alias` command. Here we just invoke `alias` once at the start, and then subsequently the expression shows in the desired form without having to apply another special command. Eg,

```
restart:  

alias(x^2=r^2-y^2):

expr := f = x^2 + y^2 + k;

                                       2
                          expr := f = r  + k
```

The `r^2` on the RHS can be computationally combined with instance of `r^2` itself.

```
expr - r^2;

                                2
                              -r  + f = k
```

But here is a drawback (which you might consider serious): it'd be nicer if the RHS of the following were displayed just as `x^2 + k`.

```
expr - y^2;

                           2        2    2
                         -y  + f = r  - y  + k
```